# I wanted to know if there are datasets available for sentiment analysis in spanish with labelled data like positive and negative

Tags: dataset, sentiment-analysis, labelled

I have been searching for a sentiment analysis dataset which contains the data in spanish and labelled data with positive and negative remarks which can be used to train/fine tune a pre-trained model.

I have been searching for a dataset but could not find one comprehensively.

Comment: This might get closed, as you are not supposed to ask for recommendations. Try searching Huggingface for data sets. Also take a look at Kaggle.  (If you've already tried those places, it'd be helpful to update your question with where you've looked; also mention what near-miss datasets you found, and why they are not suitable.)